# Docker doesnt expose Port

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, laravel-artisan

I have this docker-compose file:

```
    version: '2'
services:
    web:
        build: .
        container_name: Fila
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
            - 9000:9000
```

And this dockerfile:

```
 FROM phpdockerio/php73-fpm:latest

WORKDIR /var/www


COPY . /var/www/atendimento

WORKDIR /var/www/atendimento

RUN composer install

RUN mv .env.example .env

#RUN node index.js &

RUN php artisan key:generate 

CMD [ "php", "artisan", "serve"  ]
```

After run "docker-compose up" and execute without error,

when I tried to acess localhost:8000 in my host on navigator, i get "the connection has been reset"

inside the docker i test with "wget localhost:8000" and get the correct site. 
but in the host no.

Someone can help-me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind the host to 0.0.0.0 on the aritsan command using the --host flag.

`CMD [ "php", "artisan", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]`

Why it didn't worked?

Without setting the host, artisan will bind the server to the container localhost. The container localhost and your machine localhost are different.

Setting 0.0.0.0 will bind the server to all interfaces, including the host machine interface making it available at localhost:8000.

Comment: Using other image work without "--host 0.0.0.0" works.  Maybe some docker machines come configured. but thanks. Solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Dockerfile should add `EXPOSE`
Let add a line below into Dockerfile:
`EXPOSE 8000 9000`